# Insert statement after user registration with loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have registration form which works fine. Now I want to add second query after user is registered. This query should have loop and add exactly 10 new rows in another table. This is the query with loop

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $result = "Request successfully submitted.";

        $new_id = $db_con->lastInsertId();  

        $qty=11;   

        $sql = "INSERT INTO new_customer (user_id,value1,value2) VALUES";

        for($i=0;$i< $qty;$i++){
           $sql .= "($new_id,'1','0')";
           if($i < ($qty -1 )){
              $sql .=",";
           }            
        }                    
}
```

I'm not sure if this is correct way of doing this. After user is successfully registered I'm trying to get lastInsertId and loop and insert 10 new rows in `new_customer` table.

What is happening is that user is successfully registered but nothing is saved in `new_customer`. What is the problem here?

Comment: missing last `$conn->query($sql)` ? :)

Comment: Looks like you're not executing your inner query - you're just building up the SQL string.

Comment: where is execute statement for new_customer insert query ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, this was missing `$conn->query($sql)`. I've added it but now it's saves `0` for user_id instead of lastID

Comment: It's that `mysqli`? If yes ... you should use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Thanks @MihaiIorga. Thats works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your inner query like below:-

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Add it after inner `for` loop code.

Also if you are using `mysqli_*` then you need to use `mysqli_insert_id`:-

```
$new_id = $db_con->mysqli_insert_id;
```

Comment: Yes, now it's working perfectly. Sometimes so simple mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter  don't worry every-one does mistakes :):). BTW GLAD TO HELP YOU :):)